# lazy symbol binding error installing heroku-based rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When downloading a project hosted on heroku onto my system for the first time I receive the following error after starting the server and navigating to the project in my browser.

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _STR2CSTR
  Referenced from: /Users/blairsilverberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.4/lib/sqlite3_api.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _STR2CSTR
  Referenced from: /Users/blairsilverberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.4/lib/sqlite3_api.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap

My other rails projects in other directories work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I've never seen this issue before but it may be solvable by the Heroku support crew. Get in contact with them on irc.freenode.net #heroku. Good luck!

Comment: I figured it out. If you are running snowleopard, you need to replace: gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
 with gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :require => 'sqlite3'